# Running Aurelia new project failed

Tags: aurelia

I've just created Aurelia new project and when I run au run --watch (I am following this instructions: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/contact-manager-tutorial/1), I got this message from console. I'm quite new in JS and don't know anything about error code so can anybody tell me what's wrong?

```
{ uid: 11,
  name: 'writeBundles',
  branch: false,
  error: [SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const,function,class) not yet supported outside strict mode],
  duration: [ 1, 536524679 ],
  time: 1493576142781 }
```

Comment: maybe a node.js version issue? type `node -v` in the console and report back.

Comment: Output from console: v4.2.6

Comment: Try installing the latest Node.js version. You would not receive that message if you did so.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need node.js version 6 and above for es2015 features like `let, const and class`